# How can I display 13 selectable items on a "Mobile First" responsive webpage?

Tags: responsive-design, mobile-web, multi-selection, mobile-first

I have a 13 selectable elements list to be displayed in a Mobile First" responsive webpage.

The elements are pure text of about only one line. I have been struggling with my mind to find a solution far from typical "checkboxes".

Are there any standards or suggestions on how to display these 13 items as selectable in a 320 x 356 viewport size screen without having to make the user infinitely scroll?

Comment: I would be nice to upload some sketches of the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Scrolling isn't necessarily a bad thing. In fact [people read text on a scrolling page faster than multi-page document.](http://usabilitynews.org/the-impact-of-paging-vs-scrolling-on-reading-online-text-passages/) If you only have 13 items on the list, this is only like 2 screen height of scrolling, a lot of mobile pages out there are way lengthier. I wouldn't be terribly concern on that front.

13 items are quite a lot for somebody to take in at once though, regardless of whether it's on a small or large screen. If these selectable items can be placed into subgroups, you should consider doing so to make it easier to understand.